# How to add text into a pygame rectangle

Tags: python, class, text, pygame, drawrectangle

I have come as far as drawing a rectangle in pygame however I need to be able to get text like "Hello" into that rectangle. How can I do this? (If you can explain it as well that would be much appreciated. Thank-you)

Here is my code:

```
import pygame
import sys
from pygame.locals import *

white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)


class Pane(object):
    def __init__(self):

        pygame.init()
        pygame.display.set_caption('Box Test')
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600,400), 0, 32)
        self.screen.fill((white))
        pygame.display.update()

    def addRect(self):
        self.rect = pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, (black), (175, 75, 200, 100), 2)
        pygame.display.update()

    def addText(self):
        #This is where I want to get the text from

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Pan3 = Pane()
    Pan3.addRect()
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit(); sys.exit();
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You first have to create a [`Font`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.Font) (or [`SysFont`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.SysFont)) object. Calling the [`render`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.Font.render) method on this object will return a [`Surface`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) with the given text, which you can blit on the screen or any other [`Surface`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html).

```
import pygame
import sys
from pygame.locals import *

white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)


class Pane(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial', 25)
        pygame.display.set_caption('Box Test')
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600,400), 0, 32)
        self.screen.fill((white))
        pygame.display.update()


    def addRect(self):
        self.rect = pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, (black), (175, 75, 200, 100), 2)
        pygame.display.update()

    def addText(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.font.render('Hello!', True, (255,0,0)), (200, 100))
        pygame.display.update()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Pan3 = Pane()
    Pan3.addRect()
    Pan3.addText()
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit(); sys.exit();
```

[image]

Note that your code seems a little bit strange, since usually you do all the drawing in the main loop, not beforehand. Also, when you make heavy use of text in your program, consider caching the result of `Font.render`, since it is a very slow operation.

Comment: Thank you very much. You are my savior.

Comment: How can you make the text wrap in the box? If you have an entire sentence for example..

Comment: Okay, now how can I add the rectangle and text onto a Sprite surface?

Answer (score 0):

**Hi!**
To be honestly there is pretty good ways to write text in any place of current rect.
And now i'll show how to do it pretty easy.

---

First of all we need to create object of rect instance:

```py
                rect_obj = pygame.draw.rect(
                    screen,
                    color,
                    <your cords and margin goes here>
                )
```

Now `rect_obj` is object of `pygame.rect` instance. So, we are free to manipulate with this methods. But, beforehand lets create our rendered text object like this:

```py
                text_surface_object = pygame.font.SysFont(<your font here>, <font size here>).render(
                    <text>, True, <color>
                )
```

Afterall we are free to manipulate with all methods, as i mensioned before:
`text_rect = text_surface_object.get_rect(center=rect_obj.center)`

What is this code about?
We've just got center cords of out current rect, so easy!
Now, you need to blit ur screen like this:
 `self.game_screen.blit(text_surface_object, text_rect)`

---

Happy coding! :)