# how can I add text to these rectangles?

Tags: python, text, menu, pygame, python-3.4

This is the code I have started to use to make a start menu.

```
# we need some colours!!
black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,200)
red = (200,0,0)
green = (0, 200, 0)
bright_red = (255, 0 ,0)
bright_green = (0, 255, 0)
bright_white = (255, 255, 255)

def main():
    pygame.init()

    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 600))

    pygame.display.set_caption("CrazyPongMainMenu")

    menu = cMenu(50, 50, 20, 5, "vertical", 100, screen,
                   [("Start Game", 1, None),
                    ("Options",    2, None),
                    ("Exit",       3, None)])

    menu.set_center(True, True)

    menu.set_alignment("center", "center")

    state = 0
    prev_state = 1

    rect_list = []

    pygame.event.set_blocked(pygame.MOUSEMOTION)

    while 1:
      if prev_state != state:
         pygame.event.post(pygame.event.Event(EVENT_CHANGE_STATE, key = 0))
         prev_state = state
      e = pygame.event.wait()

      if e.type == pygame.KEYDOWN or e.type == EVENT_CHANGE_STATE:
         if state == 0:
            rect_list, state = menu.update(e, state)
         elif state == 1:
            print ("Start Game!")
            state = 0
         elif state == 2:
            print ("Options!")
            state = 0
         else:
            print ("Exit!")
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

      if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
         pygame.quit()
         sys.exit()

      mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

      #print(mouse)

      if 200+150 > mouse[0] > 200 and 250+30 > mouse[1] > 250:
          pygame.draw.rect(screen, bright_green,(200, 250, 150, 30))
      else:
          pygame.draw.rect(screen, green,(200, 250, 150, 30))

      if 200+150 > mouse[0] > 200 and 290+21 > mouse[1] > 290:
          pygame.draw.rect(screen, bright_white,(200, 290, 150, 21))
      else:
          pygame.draw.rect(screen, white,(200, 290, 150, 21))

      if 200+150 > mouse[0] > 200 and 318+25 > mouse[1] > 318:
          pygame.draw.rect(screen, bright_red,(200, 318, 150, 25))
      else:
          pygame.draw.rect(screen, red,(200, 318, 150, 25))

      pygame.display.update(rect_list)

if __name__ == ("__main__"):
   main()
```

I would like to put text onto the 3 rectangles but i don't know how to. If anybody could please tell my how to put the text onto the rectangles it will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this stack overflow question:
[How to add text into a pygame rectangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19117062/how-to-add-text-into-a-pygame-rectangle)

Specifically these bits:

```
self.font = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial', 25)

def addText(self):
    self.screen.blit(self.font.render('Hello!', True, (255,0,0)), (200, 100))
    pygame.display.update()
```

Basically you want to define a font

Then blit it onto the screen, where render takes the args (text, antialias (you want true), color)

and finally update