# I need to add text to my rectangles, how would I do this?

Tags: python, button, pygame

I need to draw text into the buttons, which can be seen as the four smaller rectangles in my program, alongside this I need to draw text onto the title as well. I am unsure on how to do this, as the structure of my program, is different to others that I have seen.

Followed other questions, and the answer they've received in an attempt to influence mine.

```
import pygame
import sys

def main():
    pygame.init()
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    fps = 60
    size = [700, 600]
    bg = [255, 255, 255]
    font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 32) 

    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

    black = (0, 0, 0)

    button = pygame.Rect(400, 400, 250, 125) 
    button2 = pygame.Rect(50, 400, 250, 125)
    button3 = pygame.Rect(400, 250, 250, 125)
    button4 = pygame.Rect(50, 250, 250, 125)

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return False


            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                mouse_pos = event.pos  # gets mouse position

                # checks if mouse position is over the button

                if button.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
                    # prints current location of mouse
                    print('Instructions'.format(mouse_pos))

                if button2.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
                    # prints current location of mouse
                    print('Controls'.format(mouse_pos))

                if button3.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
                    # prints current location of mouse
                    print('Information'.format(mouse_pos))

                if button4.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
                    # prints current location of mouse
                    print('Start Game'.format(mouse_pos))


        screen.fill(bg)

        pygame.draw.rect(screen, black, (button))  # draw button
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, black, (button2))
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, black, (button3))
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, black, (button4))
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, black, (50, 25, 600, 200))

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(fps)

    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I expect the buttons to have text on them, so in the future when I click on them they will open a new window.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to have them in separate  functions and then in a class instead?

Comment: How would I do this? I haven't really used OOP.

Comment: A  good example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19117062/how-to-add-text-into-a-pygame-rectangle

Comment: A better example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55408277/pygame-best-way-to-implement-buttons/55414264#55414264

Comment: Since you also talk about open a new window, also take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55149797/how-to-make-new-window-in-pygame/55157459?noredirect=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use [`pygame.font`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.Font.render), the you've to render the text by [`pygame.font.Font.render`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.Font.render):

e.g.

```py
 red = (255, 0, 0)
 button = pygame.Rect(400, 400, 250, 125) 
 text = font.render("button 1", True, red)
```

The result is a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface), which can be [`.blit`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) to the center of the rectangular button area:

```py
pygame.draw.rect(screen, black, button) 
textRect = text.get_rect()
textRect.center = button.center
screen.blit(text, textRect)
```

---

The other option is to use [`pygame.freetype`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/freetype.html#pygame.freetype.Font.get_sizes):

e.g.

```py
import pygame.freetype
```

```py
ft_font = pygame.freetype.SysFont('Times New Roman', 32)
```

An to render the text directly to the screen by [`pygame.freetype.Font.render_to`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/freetype.html#pygame.freetype.Font.render_to)

```py
text2 = "button 2"
textRect2 = ft_font.get_rect("button 2")
```

```py
pygame.draw.rect(screen, black, button2)
textRect2.center = button2.center
ft_font.render_to(screen, textRect2, text2, red)
```